# Allow any user in the fuse group to unmount

Tags: udev, android, systemd, fuse

I'm currently trying to write a couple of systemd/udev configuration files that will allow me to automount/unmount MTP Android devices on my Arch Linux laptop. It took me some time, but so far it works pretty well.

Now, I would like for any user with `fuse` permissions to be able to unmount the device. So far, it's only possible for the same user as the one `go-mtpfs` was started as.

I'm well aware that MTP is designed so that you can just unplug the device without consequences, but having an error message pop up when clicking "Eject" in Nautilus is kind of unexpected and not really nice.

I tried the following, but failed :

- Add myself to the `fuse` group, start `go-mtpfs` as `root` and try to unmount as myself
- Start `go-mtpfs` as the `fuse` user and group, and try to unmount as myself, also in the `fuse` group

Any idea? Also, if you have an elegant way to achieve the same thing without having to rely on the `fuse` group, I'd love to hear about it!

**systemd service** *(/etc/systemd/system/android-mtp.service)* :

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /media/Android
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/daemonize -l /var/lock/go-mtpfs.lock /usr/bin/go-mtpfs -allow-other=true /media/Android
ExecStop=/bin/umount /media/Android
ExecStopPost=/bin/rmdir /media/Android
```

**udev rule** *(/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android-mtp.rules)* :

```
# Google Nexus 7 16 Gb Bootloader & recovery mode
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e40", MODE="0666" # Bootloader
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="d001", MODE="0666" # Recovery

# Google Nexus 7 16 Gb PTP mode (camera)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e43", MODE="0666" # PTP media
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e44", MODE="0666" # PTP media with USB debug on

# Google Nexus 7 16 Gb MTP mode (multimedia device)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e41", MODE="0666" # MTP media
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e42", MODE="0666" # MTP media with USB debug on

# Google Nexus 7 MTP mode : automatic unmount when unplugged (all android versions)
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Nexus", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="4e41", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl stop android-mtp.service"
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Nexus", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="4e42", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl stop android-mtp.service"
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Nexus_7", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="4e41", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl stop android-mtp.service"
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Nexus_7", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="4e42", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl stop android-mtp.service"

# Google Nexus 7 MTP mode : automatic mount when plugged (all android versions)
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Nexus", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="4e41", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="android-mtp.service"
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Nexus", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="4e42", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="android-mtp.service"
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Nexus_7", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="4e41", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="android-mtp.service"
ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Nexus_7", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="4e42", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="android-mtp.service"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fuse` group is intended to indicate who can mount FUSE filesystems. The intent is not that anyone in that group can unmount filesystems mounted by others. Only the user doing the mounting, or root, can unmount the filesystem.

You can use [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to authorize users in the `fuse` group to run an unmount command as the same user who did the mounting. Run `visudo` to add a line like:

```
%fuse ALL = (fuse) fusermount -u /media/Android
```

Why aren't you doing the mounting as yourself? That's the usual way to use FUSE.

Comment: But then you'll have to use `sudo -u fuse fusermount -u /media/Android` every time, right? Would Nautilus (as myself) automatically guess that it can use `sudo` to unmount?

Comment: @F.X. Yes, you'd have to invoke sudo explicitly. I don't know if Nautilus can be configured to do that. Again, why not do the mounting as yourself?

Comment: Mostly because if it works great, I want to try and package it for the AUR repos in Arch. Which would fail miserably if I have a hard dependency to my username in the _udev_ rules...

Comment: @F.X. Usually physically mounted devices are mounted by the user who is logged in on the console, as tracked by something like [PolicyKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) (which [Arch Linux supports](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PolicyKit)).

Comment: Ah, interesting! I've heard about PolicyKit but never bothered learning much about it. I'll look into it, it seems that it's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks! I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Hm. Seems that I can't find out how to make Policykit mount and unmount the device. Nautilus is rigged to use `umount`, which of course fails as I'm not `root`... If you have any idea, I'd be happy to learn about it, but in the meantime, just add the info about PolicyKit in your answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @F.X. Sorry, I don't know how to make PolicyKit work with Nautilus. You should ask this as a separate question.